# SQL Update Replace part of text from a string

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I'm using MS Access and I have a table called `Backup` and a column named `ImageURL`. The `ImageURL` column has data such as: `http://domain.com/s/1234.jpg`.

I want to change the `/s/` in the URL intoto `/l/` by using an MS Access SQL Update and Replace.

When I'm trying it at the moment, it's replacing the *entire field* to `/l/`.

Thanks for your help!

Rob

Comment: @paxdiablo The link was used as an example and wasn't meant to be a valid location. All of the pertinent information is included in the question which is why there was a good answer immediately.

Comment: Apologies, I read that as a real link rather than data from the DB table. I've backticked it so it doesn't show up as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Update Backup
set ImageURL =replace(ImageURL,'/s/','/I/')
```